# Xpath: Select All elements except element with specific attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to select the text in the `<p>` node and exclude all the text in the `span` with the attribute `class="DoNotTranslate"`

Example:

```
<table>
  <p>Table0
  </p>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <span class="DoNotTranslate">add_punctuation</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="DoNotTranslate">alternate_graphic</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p>Table1
    <span class="DoNotTranslate"><span class="ScreenElement">call_number</span></span>
  </p>
</table>
```

Expected result:

```
<p>Table0</p>
<p>Table1</p>
```

I tried the below Xpath but it's not working.

```
//p/node()[not (@class="DoNotTranslate")]
```

Any other alternatives would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close enough by using either

```
//p/text()
```

or

```
//p/text()/normalize-space()
```

These should get you the text of the `<p>`elements without that of their `<span>` children:

```
Table0
Table1
```